# Trouble with flash sounds

Tags: google-chrome, audio, flash

Well, like 1 month ago everything was working fine... But some days ago I've noticed that Google Translate's sounds weren't working...

Also, some (yes, just some of them) videos on YouTube are with VERY LOW or NO sound (what is also weird, cause I've tried 'em on my phone and it did work well)

First of all, I've tried it in Internet Explorer, and it wasn't working as well (tried also in Firefox)...

I've updated Chrome's flash player, Windows' flash player, java etc... And still didn't get it working...

I've updated sound driver, installed K-Lite Mega Codec Pack and nothing...

I've reinstalled Windows thinking "of course it will work, it have to be a software issue"... And still didn't work...

But after reinstall Windows, Firefox begun to work well... But Chrome and Internet Explorer are not working yet...

(I have put this title because I still think it's a Flash Player's issue, but I'm not sure)

What could I try?

Thanks

Comment: You can post your own answer below and then accept it after a specified period of time has past. That way people with similar issues will see the answer and know that it is the answer.

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty new to the forum, thank you very much for the tip (:

Comment: No worries. The things we like are good specific questions and good specific answers to them, and we're perfectly OK with you answering your own question, because someone else might not have figured it out themselves yet and will benefit from what you've learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've just noticed that my audio configuration was set to 5.1 channel mode... But I use a headset...

So, it wasn't "flash applications" that wasn't working, it was "flash applications that use 5.1 audio channel mode"...

So, if you use a headset, follow these steps (I've done it on Windows 8.1, but it may not differ so much for others Windows versions):

- Just go to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound;
- Select your device and click on Config button and select Stereo. Test, advance and finish.

It has solved my problem, hope it helps somebody!